# C# ищу библиотеки/классы для быстропроизводительного наложения фильтра

Tags: c#, изображения, потоки-данных, bitmap

Накладываю фильтры на входящее с запросом изображение, а потом отправляю обратно
Обрабатываю это всё сейчас с помощью Bitmap, очень удобно, но производительность сильно страдает. Существуют ли какие-то библиотеки/классы специально для этих целей?

Преобразование из входящего потока в картинку

```
var Picture = new Bitmap(listenerContext.Request.InputStream);
```

Перебор по пикселям, для установки нового цвета. Метод GetPixel низкопроизводительный (как мне кажется)

```
for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++) {
        var temp = bmp.GetPixel(x,y);
        bmp.SetPixel(x,y, Color.FromArgb(temp.A,temp.R,temp.G,temp.B));
    }
```

Сохранение картинки в ответ на запрос

```
Picture.Save(listenerContext.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: ИМХО, для работы с изображениями неплохо подходит OpenCV, но: 1)  Она на c++; 2). требует усилий для изучения.

Comment: Используйте [LockBits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/5ey6h79d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @Alias а о каком речь? "FastBitmapLib" или "Fast-Bitmap" ? Смотрю через nuget, у первого 825 скачиваний, у второго 1,54к

Comment: @Alias хотя FastBitmapLib более свежий (22.11.2017)

Comment: @Alias попробовал оба варианта. В первом нет обратного конвертора из FastBitmap в Bitmap(или не нашел), а во втором используется структура FastColor в котором теряется альфа канал

Comment: @Alias пожалуйста напишите эту библиотеку в ответ, я засчитаю ответ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

мне кажется проще всего использовать [FastBitmap](https://github.com/LuizZak/FastBitmap), например таким образом:

```
using(var fastBitmap = bitmap.FastLock())
{
    fastBitmap.SetPixel(1, 1, Color.Red);//что-то делаем
};
```

что минимально отличается от использования обычного `Bitmap`; причём не нужен обратный конвертор -- при работе он изменяет существующий `Bitmap`, на котором был создан.